Фронтенд не получает данные от бэкенда после деплоя на сервер/сайт
Задеплоил backend на облачный сервер, закинул фронтенд на хостинг/сайт. После этого фронтенд перестал принимать данные с backend'а. Если запускать фронтенд с локального хоста все работает принимает и показывает. Proxy указан. Причем backend раздает данные если перейти по IP.

Пример фронтенда

const [data2, setData2] = useState(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('back6')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => setData2(res.drc))
    }, [])
    const vars2 = JSON.stringify(data2)
    const DRC= vars2.substring(12, vars2.length - 2)


Пример Бэкенда

app.get('/back6',(req, res) =>{
    connection.execute("SELECT `DRCcoin` FROM `users`", (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
          return;
        }
          res.json({
          drc: results
        });
      });
})
  app.use(cors())

На то что срезал часть текста в полученных данныхconst DRC= vars2.substring(12, vars2.length - 2) не обращайте внимание иначе не получается вывести нужную часть, без этого выводится JSON обьект.

Какие ошибки есть в консоли?

manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error. 6Error in event handler: Error: write after end
at <URL>   at y.write (<URL>)   at i.d (<URL>)   at a.emit (<URL>)   at U (<URL>)   at F (<URL>)   at B.push (<URL>)   at i._onMessage (<URL>)   at <URL>  Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON. Как и говорил выше с локального все работает, фронт получает данные с бэка

Вроде ругается на это, файл .htaccess `
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
`

Я поискал косяки и обнаружил что после того как залил фронт на хост допустим test.space fetch запросы идут на этот домен и отображаются как test.space/back6, а должно быть http://79.174.93.131:3002/back6  в package.json как "proxy": указан "http://79.174.93.131:3002". Что порекомендуете сделать?
